# How to implement an OpenVPN Client in CoDeSys?

Tags: raspberry-pi, openvpn, plc, codesys

I need to connect my [Codesys](https://codesys.com) PLC ([RevPi Connect](https://revolution.kunbus.de/)) to a Webserver using an OpenVPN Client. I could, of course, use the underlying Raspberry Pi to [install the OpenVPN](https://www.ovpn.com/en/guides/raspberry-pi-raspbian), but I would prefer to do this directly in CoDeSys. Is there any way to do this?

Thank you for your replies!